# mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de crear un sistema de recuperación de contraseñas y estoy teniendo problemas con el siguiente error:

> mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in

> *Como hay tanta información desactualizada (estoy leyendo que tienes que generar contraseñas para terceros en gmail y que no... que uses sendmail y que no... que PHPMAIL y que no) mejor directamente pregunto.*

¿Por qué ocurre este error? Dicen que necesito un SMTP (no sé qué es eso).
Estoy usando la funcion `mail()` de php en localhost.

Comment: Quieres enviar un correo usando la función mail() y una cuenta de gmail?? eso?

Comment: Te recomiendo uses la librería mailer de php, disponible aqui: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer, en esta pagina te detallan el paso a paso de la librería con el smtp de gmail. https://programacionconphp.com/enviar-email-php/

Comment: Me respondo a mi mismo: **No se si lo resolví o no pero ya me llego un correo al gmail** Lo que sucedia era lo siguiente:

Modifique el archivo **sendmail.ini y el php.ini** con los datos de mi correo y password (Así como dicen varios tutoriales incluyendo la password esa de aplicaciones de GMAIL) pero **OJO**

Apague la consola de XAMPP el **Apache y MySql** y de pronto el correo se envio y me llego al **GMAIL** (Como detesto cuando esto ocurre debí ser MUSICO u otra cosa (Gracias))

Comment: El error parece que dice claramente que está esperando un servidor SMTP en tu equipo local. Si no lo tienes, el error persistirá.

Comment: @SAGEX debes ponerlo como respuesta, no como comentario. Luego, [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Y por cierto, no solicites recomendaciones de documentaciones u otros recursos externos: ese tipo de preguntas luego terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo: No se si lo resolví o no pero ya me llego un correo al gmail Lo que sucedia era lo siguiente: Modifique el archivo sendmail.ini y el php.ini con los datos de mi correo y password (Así como dicen varios tutoriales incluyendo la password esa de aplicaciones de GMAIL) pero OJO Apague la consola de XAMPP el Apache y MySql y de pronto el correo se envio y me llego al GMAIL (Como detesto cuando esto ocurre debí ser MUSICO u otra cosa (Gracias))